# BigQuery downloading or exporting as JSON does not respect types

Tags: json, google-bigquery

Query I run in BigQuery:

```
SELECT 5 as a
```

Schema I get when I run the above query and select **Save as Table**:

[image]

JSON I get when I download the query result as JSON **or** when I export the table:

```
{"a":"5"}
```

Shouldn't this be:

```
{"a":5}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Exporting Table Data - Export Limitations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#export_limitations):

> When you export data in JSON format, INT64 (integer) data types are
>   encoded as JSON strings to preserve 64-bit precision when the data is
>   read by other systems.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using the `TO_JSON_STRING` function. [From the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#to_json_string), the representation of `INT64` is:

> Same as CAST(value AS STRING) when value is in the range of [-253,
>   253], which is the range of integers that can be represented
>   losslessly as IEEE 754 double-precision floating point numbers. Values
>   outside of this range are represented as quoted strings.[

To return query results using this function, you can use this form:

```
SELECT TO_JSON_STRING(t)
FROM (
  <your query here>
) AS t
```