# With Python, save google.cloud.bigquery.job.query.QueryJob output to local JSON file

Tags: python, json, google-bigquery

We are exporting from BigQuery to a local JSON file, in python using the google bigquery client library:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import json

bq = bigquery.Client()
full_query = """
    SELECT TO_JSON_STRING(t)
    FROM (select * from bigquery-public-data.baseball.schedules) AS t
"""
query_rowiterator = bq.query(full_query).result() # rowIterator
```

Wrapping our query in `TO_JSON_STRING` converts the output to JSON **and maintains types** ([BigQuery downloading or exporting as JSON does not respect types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50937717/bigquery-downloading-or-exporting-as-json-does-not-respect-types/50937832#50937832)), which is important for our table extraction.

How can we dump the output from `queryjob_output` into a local JSON file as quickly as possible?

Answer (score 1):

All we need to do is grab the JSON from the row at index [0]:

```
with open(f'tmp/test_output.json', 'w') as f:
    for row in query_rowiterator:
        f.write(row[0] + '\n')
```